# Using ffmpeg with Visual Studio 2013 and C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg

I'm try
main.c
    av_register_all();

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;

// Open video file
if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0)
    return -1; // Couldn't open file

if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
    return -1; // Couldn't find stream information
}
```

- I've added the include (C:\ffmpeg\include) directory to my C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories;
- I've added 
  I'm using "Zeranoe FFmpeg Build Version: git-5911eeb (2015-10-08)". I tried both 32/64bits versions as said in another question here in SO.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\error.h 110 1   FFMpeg Test
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\mem.h   94  1   FFMpeg Test
Error   9   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\mem.h   229 1   FFMpeg Test
Error   12  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\mem.h   338 1   FFMpeg Test
Error   15  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\rational.h  54  1   FFMpeg Test
Error   18  error C21in formal parameter list   c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\mem.h   338 1   FFMpeg Test
Error   20  error C2085: 'av_q2d' : not in formal parameter list    c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\rational.h  80  1   FFMpeg Test
Error   8   error C2085: 'av_mallocz_array' : not in formal parameter list  c:\ffmpeg\include\libavuormal parameter list    c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\rational.h  54  1   FFMpeg Test
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do search [static inline] replace by [__inline] in all these files

```
c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\error.h
c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\mem.h
c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\rational.h
c:\ffmpeg\include\libavutil\avutil.h
```

then update your code to this:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
    av_register_all();



    // Open video file
    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't open file

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
        return -1; // Couldn't find stream information
    return 0;
}
```

this will compile. if some other errors appears (specially linker errors) please post a new question as it will be an other problem to solve.

Comment: i successfully compiled it on my machine (Visual C++ 2010 express Edition) it should compiles on yours.

Comment: Don't change the header files, they will be replaced by their original for every new version. Instead, use a define: either #define inline __inline before the #include lines in the source code, or /Dinline=__inline as a cl.exe commandline option. FFmpeg uses this internally in its build system also.